# How to use two differents wpa_supplicant.conf files with Raspbian Stretch and Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, raspbian-stretch

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 which is using an external USB WiFi adapter. (ex: TL-WN722N). Therefore, the RPI3 has two wifi interfaces. (wlan0 (internal) and wlan1 (external))

I'm using Raspbian Stretch Lite (2017-09-07)

I would like my Raspberry Pi 3 to use two differents wpa_supplicant.conf files.
That is one config file for wlan0 and one for wlan1.

However, I'm not sure where I must specify this information.

Do I have to change the `/etc/network/interfaces` file ?

Do I have to change the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file ?

I'm a bit confused because it seems the network configuration is changing on every release of Raspbian. I'm not sure /etc/network/interfaces must be use anymore since it contains nothing except comments on Raspbian Stretch

Would it be valid to use the following configuration:

`sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant_wlan0.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant_wlan1.conf
```

Is it ok to add configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` with Raspbian Stretch ?

Answer (score 4):

To understand the recent changes to networking it helps to understand **HOW** and **WHY** they were made.

`Stretch` includes a `10-wpa_supplicant` hook so it is no longer necessary to include it in intefaces.

`Stretch` introduces [predictable network interface names](https://www.debian.org/releases/stretch/amd64/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#new-interface-names) which have been used in other distributions for some time. This means `eth0` and `wlan0` may not exist, and thus the older interfaces was no longer viable.

You should be able to use the older interfaces if you delete `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/10-wpa_supplicant` and/or `/usr/share/dhcpcd/hooks/10-wpa_supplicant` (I have not tested this myself, and do not know why there are 2 instances, although I had manually installed myself in Wheezy.)

You should also also check whether you ACTUALLY have a `wlan1`, you can force `Stretch` to use the older scheme, but the newer scheme was introduced for a reason, particularly for those with multiple network cards.

See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for more background.

It may be possible to configure `dhcpcd` to use different wpa_supplicant.conf files, although I have never investigated this.

Examination of `10-wpa_supplicant` shows it looks for files named `wpa_supplicant-"$interface".conf`, so you should be able to create interface specific files.

Comment: This is exactly it -- thanks. Preferable to other solutions I've come across, and clearly explained.

Comment: Yeah! moving `wpa_suppicant.conf` to `wpa_supplicant.conf` works perfectly.